# VTK rendering from within a QGLWidget

Tags: qt, vtk, qglwidget

I have a problem that i am trying to sort out for days already, without much success..

So, basically i want to use VTK from Qt, and i know that there is the nice QVTK module for that.
My problem is that i somehow have to do my rendering from within a QGLWidget (i am using a sort of framework where my views are qglwidgets, more or less, and i cannot really use something else than this)

i found resources such as http://prashanthudupa.livejournal.com/48221.html for rendering vtk within a QGraphicsView, but i still cannot find if or how to render a vtkrenderer from within a qglwidget

thanks for any help

Comment: Check out this thread: http://www.vtk.org/pipermail/vtkusers/2011-October/119345.html